# Tab Icon in OSX Safari different from Favicon

Tags: macos, safari, favicon

Safari seems to use a put a filter or shader on the favicon when displaying said icon in the tab bar.

**Screenshot of the Tab**
This is not how the Icon was designed and not expected.
[image: Screenshot of the Tab]

**Screenshot of the Bookmark Entry**
This is how the Icon was designed and is excepted to look.
This is how it looks in the bookmark bar and in the address bar.
[image: Screenshot of the Bookmark]

I've tried to delete the caches in the `~/Library/Safari/Favicon Cache/` because I guessed it might have been an artefact from he development. But it is not.
I've also had a good look at all the versions of the Icons that the build script generates. But all of then look as expected (in the sense of the color is always the same and does not differ).
The difference is really only in the tab bar. (For example the "Favourites" new Page in Safari also displays the icon in the expected way).

Safari: Version 14.0 (15610.1.28.1.9, 15610)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your site has a [Pinned Tab icon](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/pinnedTabs/pinnedTabs.html). To check this, look for `<link rel="mask-icon" ...>` in your `<head>` section. If you have one and you don't like it, simply remove this line, and maybe the corresponding SVG image, too.